# How to create a function by passing polygon datatype as a parameter

Tags: postgresql

I am getting stuck while executing the function,Function is getting created but while i am passing the values getting error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION INS_CCX_ply(P_ID INTEGER,P_POLY_ID INTEGER,P_POLY POLYGON)
RETURNS voiD AS
 $BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CCX_poly(id,poly_id,poly) values(P_ID,P_POLY_ID,P_POLY);
END;  
 $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;  

SELECT * FROM INS_CCX_PLY(1,11,'point((1,1),(8,6),(6,8),(10,9),(1,1))');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a text into geometry with GeomFromText:

```
GeomFromText('POINT(-126.4 45.32)')
```

The simplest way to do it is modify your function to accept a text string and then convert the string into a geometry from inside your function. Then, pass the polygon to your INSERT statement.

Answer (score 1):

In postgis there is no `POLYGON` type (see [PostGIS Types](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/reference.html#PostGIS_Types)).

There is a `geometry` type that has subtypes for points, lines, polygons and composed geometries (multiline, multipolygon, etc):

```
osm=# select 'POLYGON((26 44, 26 45, 27 45, 27 44, 26 44))'::geometry;
      geometry                                                                                          
 -----------------------
 010300000001000000050000000...

osm=# select st_asewkt('POLYGON((26 44, 26 45, 27 45, 27 44, 26 44))'::geometry);
                st_asewkt                 
------------------------------------------
 POLYGON((26 44,26 45,27 45,27 44,26 44))
```

(1 row)